# Detecting if an <option> has been selected in <select> using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I use `input:not(:placeholder-shown)` to determine if a value is in an input field.

Is there some CSS way to check if an `<option />` has been selected in a `<select>` element?

I want to style the label tag immediately following the select dropdown IF an option has been selected.

Here is an example:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
<label>Pick One</label>
```

Here is the CSS that I want to use to manipulate if an option (with a value) has been selected.

```
select.form-control:checked ~ label{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: what does your select dropdown look like? By default the first `<option>` is selected

Comment: I want to style the label tag immediately following the select dropdown IF an option has been selected.   <select class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
       </select>
       <label>Pick One</label>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the `:checked` pseudo-class also targets `<option>` tags.

Example:

```
option:checked { display:none; }
```

Source:

> http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked

**EDIT:**

If you want to target an element *outside* of your `<select>`, it can be done in a hacky way by manipulating the `:valid` css pseudo-class. Note that the `required` attribute must be enabled for the `<select>` tag to register as valid/invalid.

Example:

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

select:valid ~ label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option value="" selected>Please select an option</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<label>Please select an option</label>
```

Comment: My goal is to apply a style to a label after the select tag.  Is there a way to do that using this?  <select class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
       </select>
       <label>Pick One</label>

Comment: Edit your question with the code you are talking about and I’ll try to edit mine w a more precise answer

Comment: I have edited the original question and tried your suggestion but it did not work.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.   This will work as long as the select field is required. For optional select tags there does not seem to be a way.

Answer (score 3):

Since your `select` element doesn't have a `multiple` attribute, it isn't possible for an option not to be selected in it. (Yes, your option with no content and no value is still an option, can be selected, and is selected by default).

If it did, then what you want still wouldn't be possible. The `:checked` property would apply to the `<option>` elements, but you couldn't use it to target the `<select>` because [CSS has no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve your issue using `:has` while selecting inner `option` with an empty value that is `:not(:checked)`.

Note that it doesn't work in Firefox, since it not yet support `:has` CSS pseudo-class.

**UPDATE:**

This now works in Firefox as well, since version 119.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

/** The magic is here **/
select:has(option[value=""]:not(:checked)) + label {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

label { order: 1 }
select { order: 2 }
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="select">
    <option value>Please select...</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
  </select>
  <label for="select">Are you sure?</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works in Firefox, as of 119 which supports `:has()`.